# IJCADでレイアウト空間にオブジェクトをコピーすると図枠やビューポートがはみ出る

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2018 MechanicalでC#を使用してAutoCADのソースをIJCADに移植する作業を行っております。

機能の一つにモデル空間の図面をレイアウト空間にコピーして
指定した範囲で拡大して印刷を行う機能があるのですが、

レイアウト空間にオブジェクトをコピーした後に、図枠やビューポートがずれてしまう現象が
発生してしまいます。

テンプレートファイルをIJCADでオープンした場合は正常です。
テンプレートのイメージはこのようなものです。
[image: レイアウトテンプレート]

赤い枠がビューポートなのですが、
この中に図面をコピーして範囲を指定しズームをかけて印刷を行いたいのですが、
現状ではレイアウト空間にオブジェクトをコピーすると
このようになってしまいます。
[image: 現状]

オブジェクトをコピーした後にこのようなソースを追加してみましたが期待した結果にはなりませんでした。

```
PlotSettingsValidator icPlSetVdr = PlotSettingsValidator.Current;
icPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(lay, GrxCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Layout);
icPlSetVdr.SetUseStandardScale(lay, true);
icPlSetVdr.SetStdScaleType(lay, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit);
icPlSetVdr.SetPlotCentered(lay, true);
```

どのようにすれば図枠やビューポートが正常に表示されるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

図枠と赤い枠のビューポートがはみ出てしまっているのは、コピー元のレイアウトの用紙設定とコピー先のレイアウトの用紙設定の余白の設定が違うために発生していると思います。
大きくはみ出てしまっているビュポートは、ビューポートの左下の点の座標が図枠内の座標になるように、ビューポートを移動してみてください。